# Dynamicall add field/value pairs in react hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

So, I know in class based React, you can dynamically add form field name/value pairs as you go through the form using code such as:

```
this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
```

However, I have not been able to find a similar way of doing this using hooks.  I've tried doing:

```
useState([...fields, {[e.target.name]: e.target.value}]);
```

and

```
useState(field => [...field, {[e.target.name]: e.target.value}];
```

But neither seem to work as expected.  Each time I run the above, I get an appended array incrementing the typed value for each item in the array.  I've also tried the following to overwrite the name/value in place, but once you tab to the next field, the previous isn't retained.

```
useState([e.target.name]: e.target.value);
```

All that being said, what is the proper way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

You don't use `useState` directly to update function components state, you use it to create a state.

For eg:

```
const [formData, setFormData] = useState({});
```

creates a state called `formData` for you component, which is initially an empty object.

You should use the method `setFormData` to update it. Something like:

```
setFormData((prevState => {
   return {...prevState, ...{[e.target.name]: e.target.value}}
});
```

Comment: Sorry, when I was using useState as the updater, it was meant to be generic.  I am in fact using a custom hook to update state.